# Do HTTP GET & POST respect order when multiple values are given for a key?

Tags: http, post, parameters, get

In a current project the UI posts an ordered list of ids of several files under one key to tell the server in which order the files need to be processed:

```
file[]=18&file[]=20&...
```

So far the order is preserved when handing this over from client to server, however I could find no specification whether the HTTP protocol keeps the parameters in the specified order. So the question is, is it safe to depend on the given order, or should I implement a workaround to assign each file id a specific order? E.g.

```
file_18=0&file_20=1&...
```

**Edit:**
jQuery Ui has a [serialize method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize), that will pass the parameters just in the initial way that I described above:

> foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2

This is for a sortable list, so I assume they know what they are doing.

Comment: No this is not guaranteed. And your 'workaround' is actually a preferred way to do it.

Comment: I added the way that jQuery UI does it above. That would contradict your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server. In general, the order is ***guaranteed by the TCP protocol***. If you can read in this order, your HTTP parser stores the parameters in the direct sequence - do not worry. Nobody will be changing these parameters in some places.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't specify the format of GET and POST data. So they just get passed as blobs of data.

It is up to your form data parser to maintain the order (I'm not aware of any that don't (for identically named fields).